# Как в тесте проверить, что форма принадлежит классу из forms?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
...
response = self.authorized_client.get(reverse('posts:post_create'))
        form_fields = {
            'text': forms.fields.CharField,
            'group': forms.fields.ChoiceField,
            'image': forms.fields.ImageField

        }
        for field_name, field_type in form_fields.items():
            with self.subTest(name=field_name, type=field_type):
                form = response.context.get('form')
                self.assertIsNotNone(form)
                self.assertIsInstance(form, PostForm)
...
```

Comment: А так как вы проверяете - не работает?

Comment: А, ну судя по ошибке это не форма, это поле формы

Comment: Нужно протестить что поля формы принадлежат классу PostForm

Comment: Ну, я деталей не знаю, но чисто из бытовой логики как поле, то есть Field, может принадлежать классу Form - мне непонятно.

Comment: А теперь та же ошибка или другая?

Comment: Сейчас ошибки нет, но я не уверен, что тест выполняет, то что я хочу. Можно мне "разжевать" что тут происходит: form = response.context.get('form')  уже "каша" в голове от кода...

Answer (score 0):

собственно вот эта проверка и проверяет `self.assertIsInstance(form, PostForm)`